# tornado web http request blocks other requests, how to not block other requests

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, tornado, nonblocking

```
import tornado.web
import Queue

QUEUE = Queue.Queue()

class HandlerA( tornado.web.RequestHandler ):
    def get(self):
        global QUEUE
        self.finish(QUEUE.get_nowait())

class HandlerB( tornado.web.RequestHandler ):
    def get(self):
        global QUEUE
        QUEUE.put('Hello')
        self.finish('In queue.')
```

**Problem:** HandlerA blocks HandlerB for 10 seconds.

1. Browser A handled by HandlerA and waits...
2. Browser B handled by HandlerB and waits.... till timeout exceptions

**Goal**

1. Browser A handled by HandlerA and waits...
2. Browser B handled by HandlerB and **returns**
3. HandlerA **returns** after dequeuing

Is this an issue with Non-blocking, async, epoll or sockets?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I updated this code with a new thread to handle the Queue.get_nowait() request. Which I fear is a HORRIBLE solution considering I'm going to have thousands of requests at once and would therefore have thousands of threads at once. I'm considering moving to a `epoll` style in the near future.

```
class HandlerA( tornado.web.RequestHandler ):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
       thread.start_new_thread(self.get_next)

    def get_next(self):
        global QUEUE
        self.finish(QUEUE.get_nowait())
```

Now this is not the best way to handle it... but at least its a start.

**SOLUTION**

Found here [Running blocking code in Tornado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293238/running-blocking-code-in-tornado/14298520)

Comment: This question/issue is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293238/running-blocking-code-in-tornado/14298520

Answer (score 1):

This is Python. So, `time.sleep` will always block the flow! In order to call action after 10 seconds with Tornado, you need to use `tornado.ioloop.add_timeout` function and pass callback as param. [Docs for more information](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_callback).

Comment: Your are correct. My problem is not using time.sleep, sorry for the confusion. But I'm using Queue.Queue synchronous blocking. Trying to pass information from one browser to another. Does this make more sense? I need to have HandlerA do a Queue.Queue.get_nowait() waiting for HandlerB to do a Queue.Queue.put() call. I'll edit the posting to reflect this. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Why are you using Queue at all - unless your real code has threads running around you don't need the overhead.  You could just use a list or a deque for push/pop operations.

Comment: I'm using Queue because it is crucial to have synchronicity between two different connections.
Ex. Client 1 requests and queues "Hello, world". Client 2 connects and dequeues the "Hello, world". But if client 1 does not send the hello: client 2 will wait (till timeout) for client 1 to data into the queue.