# Running blocking code in Tornado

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I have a tornado app and I want to to use a blocking library to accomplish something. In cases where it's not possible to rewrite the library in an async manner, what's the way to execute it in tornado?

For example, I'd like to be able to put an `@asynchronous` decorator on a request handler, in it start some long running function that will just return a response once it's done. I can't just put a callback. The easiest example is of course what is the right way to sleep for 10 seconds without blocking tornado's only thread?

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you want to block tornado? Because you can always do `time.sleep(10)` but I'm sure you want to do something else...

Comment: @StevePeak thanks, I added another paragraph

Comment: Funny, I have this same concept in one of my applications. See my SO here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961863/tornado-web-http-request-blocks-other-requests-how-to-not-block-other-requests is you issue related to this? Either way I would love to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what I wanted was simply creating a new thread/process, and that the actual act of calling back to tornado needs to be done with `IOLoop.instance().add_callback`

More information is available [here](http://tornadogists.org/2185380/)

Comment: I posted a question about the performance of this script. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306360/performance-of-asynchronous-request-handler-with-blocking-tasks-handled-by-work

Answer (score 2):

The code the accepted answer refers to [is available on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14306360/1599229).

Another approach is detailed in a blog post [here](http://lbolla.info/blog/2013/01/22/blocking-tornado), along with [a full working gist](https://gist.github.com/lbolla/4594879). Here is a re-posting of the code from the gist:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial, wraps
import time

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


EXECUTOR = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)


def unblock(f):

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        self = args[0]

        def callback(future):
            self.write(future.result())
            self.finish()

        EXECUTOR.submit(
            partial(f, *args, **kwargs)
        ).add_done_callback(
            lambda future: tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(
                partial(callback, future)))

    return wrapper


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world %s" % time.time())


class SleepHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @unblock
    def get(self, n):
        time.sleep(float(n))
        return "Awake! %s" % time.time()


class SleepAsyncHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self, n):

        def callback(future):
            self.write(future.result())
            self.finish()

        EXECUTOR.submit(
            partial(self.get_, n)
        ).add_done_callback(
            lambda future: tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(
                partial(callback, future)))

    def get_(self, n):
        time.sleep(float(n))
        return "Awake! %s" % time.time()


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"/sleep/(\d+)", SleepHandler),
    (r"/sleep_async/(\d+)", SleepAsyncHandler),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example below.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import time

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self, request):
        if request is None:
            self.application.go = False
            self.write("Waiting for GET @ http://localhost:8888/go...<br>")
            self.flush()
            self._do_wait()
        else:
            self.application.go = True
            self.finish('Thanks!')

    def _do_wait(self, timeout_trys=10):
        if self.application.go:
            self.write('Finish')
            self.finish()
        else:
            self.write("Sleeping 2 second, timeout_trys=%s<br>" % timeout_trys)
            self.flush()
            tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(time.time() + 2, 
                lambda: self._do_wait(timeout_trys-1))


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/(\w+)?", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: thanks, but I think what I was looking for is more like I showed in my answer here