# Performance of: asynchronous request handler with blocking tasks handled by worker pool

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

How is the performance of this script: http://tornadogists.org/2185380/ copied below.

```
from time import sleep
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import Application, asynchronous, RequestHandler
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

_workers = ThreadPool(10)

def run_background(func, callback, args=(), kwds={}):
    def _callback(result):
        IOLoop.instance().add_callback(lambda: callback(result))
    _workers.apply_async(func, args, kwds, _callback)

# blocking task like querying to MySQL
def blocking_task(n):
    sleep(n)
    return n

class Handler(RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
    def get(self):
        run_background(blocking_task, self.on_complete, (10,))

    def on_complete(self, res):
        self.write("Test {0}<br/>".format(res))
        self.finish()

HTTPServer(Application([("/", Handler)],debug=True)).listen(8888)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

1. My application will have way over **1,000 req/sec**.
2. Each request will last from 2-30 seconds, averaging about 6 seconds

   - Simply averaging `sleep(6)`
3. Block IO by using something like `redis BLPOP` or `Queue.get_nowait()`

Comment: Are your tasks CPU intensive? If so, you might want to spread this across multiple CPUs. To do that though, you would need to use an alternate implementation of Python that doesn't have GIL - like Jython or IronPython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overall pattern is fine, with the caveat that thanks to the GIL, your thread pool will only be able to use a single CPU, and you'll need to use multiple processes to make full use of the available hardware.

Taking a closer look at the numbers, 10 threads is way too small if your requests are really going to average 6 seconds each.  You've got 6000 seconds worth of work coming in every second, so you need a total of at least 6000 threads across all your processes (and that's assuming the 6 seconds is really just blocking on external events and the CPU cost in the python process is negligible).  I'm not sure how many threads a modern system can handle, but 6000 Python threads doesn't sound like a great idea.  If you've really got 6 seconds of blocking per request (and thousands of requests/sec) it sounds like it would be worthwhile to convert these blocking functions to be asynchronous.

Comment: Sorry for delay, didn't see in thread. I've updated my code to reflect the concerns your brought up. Still in the works... but my techniques are being refined. Thanks for your advice Ben!